# Chipset G31 drivers for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, installation, chipset

I finally decided to upgrade my quite old system to Windows 7 x64 (from Vista x86) and I have the following question:

The site for my motherboard (ASUS P5KPL AM SE) lists the G31 drivers for Win 7 as "release candidate". On the other hand, Intel's site gives a different version of the drivers that is apparently not a release candidate. Which one should I install and would it make a difference? Or maybe I should just get the Intel® Chipset Software Installation Utility for series 8,7,6,5,4,3,900 (I believe G31 is in series 3)

Comment: I would download them from Asus' site. There shouldn't be a difference between the two.

Comment: have you tried installing Win 7?  it may have the drivers built in

Answer (score 0):

Install the drivers from ASUS and if you ran into issues, try the newer ones from Intel.